# Is there any 100% safe way to download an iso of Windows?

Tags: windows, exploit, nsa, reinstall

I've been concerned about security and I have been reading a lot about [stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet) and hearing a lot lately about the leaked NSA exploits and the more recent leaked exploits [NYtimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/12/us/nsa-shadow-brokers.html?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=newsletter_axiosam&stream=top-stories&_r=0&mtrref=undefined)  and how they are being sold on the black market. That got me thinking about how important a clean install of Windows is. Then I was thinking that maybe having a physical OS install disk is the only way to know for sure that you are installing a clean install of Windows.

## How safe is it to download an .iso of Windows directly from Microsoft?

Using for example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Is it farfetched to consider the possibility that an iso could be compromised while it is being downloaded?

- **Could it be modified while it is being downloaded by**

  1. Someone attacking the ISP
  2. An exploit on the router
  3. A virus on the computer.
- **More importantly after the iso is downloaded could there be an exploit to**

  1. Spoof the SHA1 using something similar to [link](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html)
  2. Trick common software like [hash calculator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hash-calculator/) that checks SHA1 into saying that it is correct even if it is not.

Are these potentially ways to compromise a download of Windows OS?

Comment: this has been answered several times here - search for "infected iso"

Comment: and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86234/how-do-i-check-the-hash-of-an-iso